# Vue.js - Trying to bind dynamic images... what should I do?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've started a new project using Vue-CLI 3 and Webpack 4. Everything works fine, but for some reason I'm not able to bind images. The structure that I have is so easy:

```
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in items">
      {{ item.name }}
      <img :src="'../public/images/' + item.img">
   </div>
</div>
```

And then, my items array. It comes from my Store in Vuex.

```
items = [
   {
      name: 'my-name-1',
      img: 'image-1.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'my-name-2',
      img: 'image-2.png'
   },
   {
      name: 'my-name-3',
      img: 'image-3.png'
   }
]
```

I've been playing with Webpack, because I guess the problem comes from there. I've changed some configurations, I've tested with diferents paths (./, ../, ~/...) but nothing works... What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `item` is out of scope/undefined in img, it's only bound inside the v-for div, therefor `<img .. item.img` will not work

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Fixed. This doesn't work anyway.

Comment: well if `items = [` is your real code - that its not valid js/json (should be `{items : [...]}`) - see [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmYexW) for a working demo

Answer (score 9):

To have dynamic image paths, use `require()`:

```
<img :src="require('../public/images/' + item.img)">
```

---

Tip: leave the least variation possible in the `require` args. So if you know all images will have the extension `.png`, do:

```
<img :src="require('../public/images/' + item + '.png')">
```

Of course, the string `item` should not have the extension anymore.

This happens because webpack actually parses that `require()` argument and includes in the bundle all files that *may* match it. The more specific your arg is, the less files that will never be used will be included in the bundle by webpack.

Comment: It seems `require()` is no longer present in the latest vue (3.x) - at least not without additional imports.